# Node.js & MariaDB: Cannot delete row due to failed constraint check, even though referenced rows are already gone

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

**My problem**

First up I get this error in Node.js:

> Fehler beim löschen des Fahrzeugs: Error: ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED_2: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('gta5'.'vehicle_maintenance', CONSTRAINT 'FOREIGN_KEY_vehicleid' FOREIGN KEY ('vehicleid') REFERENCES 'vehicles' ('vehicleid'))

There is no record left in `vehicle_maintenance`, as a result there is also no reference left. You can see, that I delete the entries in `vehicle_maintenance`, before trying to delete the vehicle itself. I even set up a timeout, to be sure, that the script is not to fast. But that makes no sense, because I am already waiting for the callback. So the work should be done.

**Tables**

Table `vehicles`. The main table for all vehicles with params like color, owner etc...

Table `vehicle_maintenance`. The table for maintenance work done at any given km and time.

**What is my plan?**
I just don't want any old rows in table `vehicle_maintenance`, when referenced vehicle in `vehicles` is already gone.
On the other hand, I don't want to use `CASCADE`, because the vehicle can exist even when the maintenance records are not present.

```
ALTER TABLE `vehicle_maintenance` ADD CONSTRAINT 'FOREIGN_KEY_vehicleid' FOREIGN KEY ('vehicleid') REFERENCES 'vehicles'('vehicleid') ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

```
let delVehMaintenanceSQL = "DELETE FROM vehicle_maintenance WHERE vehicleid = '" + vid + "'";
con.query(delVehMaintenanceSQL, function (error){
    if(error){
        console.log("[FEHLER][VEH] Fehler beim löschen des Fahrzeug-Checkhefts: " + error);
        player.outputChatBox("!{red}Fehler beim löschen des Fahrzeugs! Fehlercode: 4687.");
    }else{
        setTimeout(function () {
            let sql = "DELETE FROM vehicles WHERE vehicleid = '" + vid + "'";
            con.query(sql, function(err) {
                if(err){
                    console.log("Fehler beim löschen des Fahrzeugs: " + err);
                    player.outputChatBox("!{red}Fehler beim löschen des Fahrzeugs! Fehlercode: 6874.");
                }else{
                    player.outputChatBox("!{green}Fahrzeug wurde gelöscht.");
                    console.log("------------------------------DELETE-VEH--------------------------------");
                    console.log(player.pFullName + " hat ein Fahrzeug (" + vid + ") gelöscht. Besitzer: " + owner);
                    console.log("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    vehicle.destroy();
                }
            });
        }, 100)    
    }
});
```

**Output of `show create table vehicles`**

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
  `vehicleid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modelName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engineHealth` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 1000,
  `tank` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `tank_max` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `fuelType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_filled_with` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `km` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `km2` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `owner` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `key_1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `key_2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `plate` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `color1` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `color2` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `x` double NOT NULL,
  `y` double NOT NULL,
  `z` double NOT NULL,
  `rotation_x` double NOT NULL,
  `rotation_y` double NOT NULL,
  `rotation_z` double NOT NULL,
  `dirt_lvl` double NOT NULL,
  `sa_remote` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sa_keyless_go` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `sa_coming_home` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sa_signal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `beladen` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `beladen_typ` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `warSlot` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warAutohaus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `isRegistered` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `registeredTo` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `vehicle_condition` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
  `vehicle_defects` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `kofferraum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kofferraumInhalt` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vehicleid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

**Output of `show create table vehicle_maintenance`**

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicle_maintenance` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vehicleid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `km` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FOREIGN_KEY_vehicleid` (`vehicleid`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FOREIGN_KEY_vehicleid` FOREIGN KEY (`vehicleid`) REFERENCES `vehicles` (`vehicleid`) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Am I missing out something? Imho everything looks correct.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table vehicles` and `show create table vehicle_maintenance`

Comment: @ysth I have edited my post.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the "direction" of cascading deletes. It means that all maintenance records will be deleted when a vehicle is deleted. Deleting a maintenance record does not have any influence whatsoever on the vehicles table. So if I understand you correctly, you probably just should define the cascading delete

Comment: And I'm asking myself, why you are putting you vehicleid between quotes? Your table definition shows it's a number

Comment: the unique key in vehicle_maintenance is also strange; do you really not want more than one maintenance record for a vehicle?

Comment: (doesn't explain the problem you are seeing, but the create tables should make it easy for someone to try it out)

Comment: @derpirscher You are right, integers should work without qoutes. Just the power of habit. But that works as well.
Furthermore you are also right with the behaviour of cascade. This would be a correct way to get my desired outcome, but that will not solve the issue that I am having. The entry in `vehicle_maintenance` is already gone, but still the constraint check fails.

Comment: @ysth Yes, it was an accident. Changed it to index.

Comment: You're right, this won't solve your current issue and I don't see any obvious problem with your code. Can you make sure there is indeed no reference to the vehicle anymore? And just as a sidenote. You shouldn't add parameters to queries with string concatenation but use parametrized queries.

Comment: Yes I am sure that there is no other reference. This DB is rather small. Nontheless: `select distinct concat(table_schema, '.', table_name) as foreign_table,
       '>-' as rel,
       concat(referenced_table_schema, '.', referenced_table_name) 
       as primary_table
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where referenced_table_name = 'vehicles'
      and table_schema = 'gta5'
order by foreign_table;` gives me `gta5.vehicle_maintenance >- gta5.vehicles`

Comment: you show cascade as being set, which makes the error even more puzzling.  are you sure you are getting this error even with on delete cascade?

Comment: if it were not for that, I would guess that somehow either the vid is changing between the two queries or they are running in separate connection sessions and the maintenance delete isn't committed.

Comment: Can you try setting `ON DELETE CASCADE` and then delete that vehicle again (ie just `DELETE FROM vehicles WHERE vehicleid = 123`). Please try this in the maridadb client (ie not via your app). If that still doesn't work, then there is some serious issue with your database,  some index may be corrupted ...

Comment: I'm sorry. The `ON DELETE CASCADE` statement was an accident in the show create table query. With `ON DELETE CASCADE` it works. I changed my code to just one query like `DELETE FROM vehicles WHERE vehicleid = x` and the corresponding rows are also gone. When I query both queries in one line, seperated with `;` (firstly delete maintenance entries, secondly the vehicle itself) via console it works just fine. It must be a problem in node.js/the mariadb/mysql package. As I am waiting for the (success) callback, the changes must have been already committed. P.s. the vehid is the same in both querys